# defining relationships between terms in a taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there a module which allows you to define a relationship between some terms in a taxonomy? Specifically, being adjacent? The taxonomy is flat.
So that Auckland has Northland and Waikato as neighbours (the use case would be to build a view of events in nearby regions)

My searching can't have used the right names for this - I'm not finding anything :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship functionality exists in Drupal core - no need for a contributed module.

Go to `/admin/structure/taxonomy/YOUR_VOCABULARY/fields` and add a new field of type **Term reference**, click *Save*.

On the next screen

1. change **Number of values** from *1* to **Unlimited**
2. choose the same vocabulary you added the field to in the **Vocabulary** dropdown.

Then edit each term and add the neighbouring regions to it.